# seven segment display with width

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm in the process of making a seven segment display emulator in python and have run into a small problem. What I have done is make a list for each number that has a series of numbers representing a character, like so `["000", "001", "000", "001", "000"]` This represents the number 1, with 0 been a space, 1 been a pipe character (|) and 2 been a dash.

This works fine for a width of 1 but I want it to be able to go to any width. I've tried doing this by multiplying the character count by the width e.g the number one with a width of two would look like `["000000", "000011", "000000", "000011", "000000"]`

The problem I am having is when it encounters a pipe character it will print it on the same line rather than underneath it. Like so '| |' when it should be like

|
|

I've tried using `\n` to print it on a new line but this messes everything else up.

Any suggestions on how do this in a better way or how to fix my problem would be appreciated.

Here is my code.

```
  uno = ["000", "001", "000", "001", "000"]
  temp = ""
    width = 2
    for line in uno:
    temp = ""
    for char in line:
        temp += char * width
    temp = temp.replace('0', ' ').replace("1", "|").replace('2', '-')
    print(temp)
```

Example Output

```
||

||
```

Wanted Output

```
|
|

|
|
```

Thanks

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include the code that produces these results?

Comment: Add an example how would you like the output to look like when you go with the width=2.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18424973/235698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a bit to grasp your input format. It's a bit silly to use 15 characters than can take any of three values to represent what is, almost by definition a seven bit output. It does make rendering easy, I guess.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to be able to turn your current `width=1` output, where an `8` looks like this:

```
 -
| |
 -
| |
 -
```

To a scaled up version, where for `width=2` an `8` would look like:

```
 --
|  |
|  |
 --
|  |
|  |
 --
```

Currently, a single-width `8` requires the input `['020', '101', '020', '101', '020']`. If you want to use the same rendering method (where you simply replace the numbers with characters), you need to translate this to: `['0220', '1001', '1001', '0220', '1001', '1001', '0220']` to increase the size.

Notice that the lines with the `1`s get repeated as a whole and the middle character is repeated on every line.

Here's a function that translates from width 1 to any other width:

```
def scale(code, factor):
    if factor == 1:
        return code

    result = ["{}{}{}".format(line[0], line[1:-1]*factor, line[-1])  # widen
              for line in code]

    for i in range(len(result)-2, 0, -2):
        result[i:i+1] = result[i:i+1]*factor       # stretch vertically

    return result

def render(code):
    for line in code:
        print(line.replace('0', ' ').replace('1', '|').replace('2', '-'))
```

Example output:

```
>>> render(['020', '101', '020', '101', '020'])
 - 
| |
 - 
| |
 - 
>>> render(scale(['020', '101', '020', '101', '020'], 2))
 -- 
|  |
|  |
 -- 
|  |
|  |
 -- 
>>> render(scale(['020', '101', '020', '101', '020'], 3))
 --- 
|   |
|   |
|   |
 --- 
|   |
|   |
|   |
 ---
```

Comment: I think this answer makes the question make sense... Nice one... +1